# TestNG single dataProvider/multiple tests/running in parallel?

Tags: java, testng

I've engineered a test suite for the project I'm working on using TestNG where all the tests share a common data provider that reads parameter data from the XML file and feeds it to the test instance. I'm wondering if there's a way to enable the parallel option in the suite XML file without all the tests blowing up because they are all endeavouring to talk to the same static data provider at the same time. I already know that I can enable 'parallel' at the DataProvider level, but that will only allow multiple data providers to be accessed at the same time, which seems a silly solution in this case because it would necessitate my creating multiple instances of the exact same DP - one per test - in order to get the effect I'm looking for.

thanks in advance for your insights!

*EDIT1* Turns out this wasn't actually a testNG problem - something the test class extends has a static member which was creating lots-o-problems.

Comment: I am not sure I get your issue.  Why would u need to create one dp per test?  If you setup dp in parallel that would mean it would start your test instances in parallel instead of sequentially.

Comment: @niharika_neo If you do that in a setup with multiple tests that share the same data provider, everything does kick off in parallel but all the tests fail immediately because they start without the dataProvider actually forking over the goods.